# External CSS doesn't work, while inline styling does work

Tags: html, css

If I write this in my external css file it does make 'a' text green.

```
.ink-navigation ul.menu.black li ul.submenu li a {
   color: green;
}
```

but this works

```
<nav class="ink-navigation"> 
   <ul class="menu black">
     <li>
       <ul class="submenu">
         <li>
           <a href="#" title="" style="color:green">This is a text</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Does anybody knows why the external css does not work?

Comment: Post your HTML, you probably just need to fix the `href` path

Comment: As @Brian said, make sure you linked to a file, inspect your `head` element and look for the file in question. Right-click, open in a new tab, and see if it opens. The only other problem I can think of is that it's getting overriden.

Comment: the external css has correct setup, only that text color would not change other properties changes when changed. Also putting color: green!important; at the bottom of css did not work.

Comment: @Simon please post your comment as answer, I want to give you credit you solved the issue.

Comment: @TwitterBootstrap done :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS executes in order; therefore rules at the bottom of your CSS are given higher priority and override any prior rules. Also, inline CSS executes after the stylesheet and since it is seen last, it takes priority.

*A simple fix would be to add important to the colour... e.g:*

- `color: green!important;`

On a side note, I highly recommend that you reduce your code by removing unnecessary bloat which actually contributes to such problems as this. If `.ink-navigation` is unique you don't need to use your current format. Use `.ink-navigation ul li ul li a {}` or even `.ink-navigation .submenu a {}`. However, if you have existing rules with the larger format then that will override the shorter format, so its important to address all occurrences if you want to shorten your code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your external CSS is not linked to correctly in your HTML.

Example of how to link a CSS file that's in the same folder as your HTML:

`<link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Also, just a tip - it's usually clearer code to understand and debug if you just put an id or class (i.e. `id="green-title"`) as an attribute for your tag.

```
#green-title {
color: green;
}
```

Comment: the external css has correct setup, only that text color would not change.

Comment: You should post up your HTML in order to get better answers - we only know as much as you've shared.  Try adding an 'id' to the link and debugging using that. Your '.ink-navigation....etc.' is too long.

Answer (score 0):

In the head tag ,first Place bootstrap file on the top, then css file below. with this you don't want to use !important in every style code.

Answer (score -1):

Where have you attached your css external files?

You should have something like this in your header

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/cssFile.css">
```

Comment: With this your css File should be in a subdirectory of your project root in a folder called CSS. And use an underscore for class names seperated by space ......so .ink-navigation ul.menu_black li ul.submenu li a .                         You can also access your class by just calling the .submenu > li method.

Comment: the external css has correct setup, only that text color would not change.

Comment: Try to add your code in a <style> tag in your HTML <head>. See if that works. If it does then its a reference error if not, then you need to explain your problem a little more so we can help